# How do I fix my For loop and Random problem in Android?

Tags: java, android, for-loop

**PlayerData class**

```
public class PlayerData{

    int id; // id means Player's order
    boolean isTeacher;

    public PlayerData() {

    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTeacher() {
        isTeacher = true;
    }
}
```

**Singleton  class**

```
 public class Singleton {

    public int time;
    public int total; // number of total players
    public int teacher; // number of teachers
    public int student; // number of students

    public int count = 1;
    public String keyWord; // 
    ArrayList<PlayerData> playerArrayList = new ArrayList<PlayerData>();

    // method init creates Objects of players
    public void init() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            PlayerData player = new PlayerData();
            player.setID(i);  // set id
            playerArrayList.add(player); // add player Object to ArrayList
        }
    }

    public void JobSelection() {

        int a[] = new int[teacher]; // Make array to the number I will select
        Random r = new Random(); // Random Object
        PlayerData player = new PlayerData();
        for (int i = 0; i < teacher; i++)    // for loop to select Teachers 
        {
            a[i] = r.nextInt(total) + 1; //select a number from 1~total and Save in a[0]~a[total]
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) //for loop to avoid overlap
            {
                if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                    i--;
                }
            }

            if (a[i] == player.id) { 
                playerArrayList.get(player.id - 1).isTeacher = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

**RoleSelection class**

```
 public class RoleSelection extends AppCompatActivity {
    Singleton s1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    PlayerData player = new PlayerData();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_role_selection07_03);

        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textJobConfirm);

        if (s1.playerArrayList.get(s1.player.id-1).isTeacher == true) {
            t1.setText(" You job is Teacher ");
        } else {
            t1.setText(" Your job is Student ");
```

I am making an app game whose job consists of only Teacher and Student.
Codes above shows my app.

1. There is a player class that has its data and setters
2. There is a Singleton class that saves values in a variable such as total(total players), teacher, student etc..
   Also Singleton class has ArrayList that creates Player's Objects.
3. In Singleton class I made 2 methods: One for creating Objects in a ArrayList, the other for giving objects their jobs.
4. JobSelection Method is trying to give a job to each player. For example if the total player chosen at game setting is 10 and teacher chosen is 4, I have to give 4 teacher jobs randomly to 10 player objects.
5. After giving the players a job, I wrote code in 'Role Selection' class to setText differently considering player's job.

I don't have any errors in my logcat or in my app.
However, I am only receiving "Your Job is Student". I guess the JobSelection method haven't worked well.
So I tried to fix these codes

```
 for (int i = 0; i < teacher; i++)    // for loop to select Teachers 
    {
        a[i] = r.nextInt(total) + 1; //select a number from 1~total and Save in a[0]~a[total]
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) //for loop to avoid overlap
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                i--;
            }
        }

        if (a[i] == player.id) { 
            playerArrayList.get(player.id - 1).isTeacher = true;
        }
    }
```

But I failed to solve these problems...

I will be grateful if someone answers me how can I make jobs distributed and see different TextView according to their jobs. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by these codes:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < teacher; i++)    
    {
        a[i] = r.nextInt(total) + 1; 
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                i--;
            }
        }

        if (playerArrayList.get(a[i] - 1).id == a[i]) { 
            playerArrayList.get(a[i] - 1).setTeacher();
        }

    }
}
```